# Which of the following statement is not necessarily true for the product of rings $R \times R$ when it is true for $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

$R$ is a ring. Which of the following statements is not necessarily true for the product of rings $R \times R$ when it is true for $R$?

A. There exists some generator whose order is finite.

B. $R$ is commutative.

C. There exist some $a \not= 0$, and $a^2 = 0$.

D. $R$ is a field.

E. $R$ is finite.

I think I can exclude B, and I think the answer might be D. Could anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R$ is a field, then the element $(1, 0) \in R \times R$ is a zero divisor in the product ring, so $R \times R$ cannot be a field.

---

On the other hand, if $R$ is commutative, then $R \times R$ is as well; we have

$$(r, s) (r', s') = (rr', ss') = (r'r, s's) = (r', s')(r,s)$$

If $R$ is finite, then $R \times R = \{(r, s) : r, s \in R\}$ has cardinality $|R|^2$ as a set, and is also finite.

If $R$ has an element $a \ne 0$ with $a^2 = 0$, what can you say about $(a, 0)$ in the product ring?

This also rules out (B), (C) and (E).